# Spelling: Bioinformatic(s) solutions

Tags: nouns, adjectives, word-usage

When discussing solutions in the field of [Bioinformatics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioinformatics), should they be called "bioinformatic solutions" or "bioinformatics solutions"? My logic (as a *non-native speaker*) kind of prefers the first one, while the latter seems to be used more widely, for example in a somewhat similar case of "software" instead of "solutions": [List of open-source bioinformatics software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_open-source_bioinformatics_software).

Or can both be correct, "bioinformatics" as a noun, and "bioinformatic" as an adjective?

Of course this could probably be circumvented by rephrasing, but here I'm really after this specific usage.

Comment: Bioinformatics solutions are solutions that are used in the field of bioinformatics. Bioinformatic solutions are solutions whose texture, structure, or consistency is bioinformatic. *Whatever that even means*. Is the texture of your solution bioinformatic?

Comment: This question is similar to a recent one on *physics* although it appears that *bioinformatic* makes more sense than *physic*. Agree with @RegDwight.

Comment: This is one of the few cases where we might consider inserting a hyphen, *bio-informatics* (otherwise, there is the weird sequence *ioi*)---standard practice seems to avoid the hyphen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Merriam-Webster:

> **bioinformatics**: the collection, classification, storage, and analysis of biochemical and biological information using computers
>   especially as applied to molecular genetics and genomics

More to the point, M-W provides **bioinformatic** as the adjectival form of **bioinformatics**, so it appears that "**bioinformatic** solutions" is an acceptable phrase.

That said, I'm not sure I would use "**bioinformatic** solutions" unless I was trying to contrast "**bioinformatic** solutions" with "**non-bioinformatic** solutions". Even then, I would probably use "**bioinformatics** solutions" or "**bioinformatics-based** solutions", as it's not obvious what is to be gained by using "**bioinformatic** solutions", but that appears to be purely a matter of taste.